# Django dynamic menu in global view (base.html) to be visible in all templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, global-variables, inclusion

I have built the website with couple templates but I would like to achieve how to read menu from DB in the base.html that would be visible on entire website, I dont want to add it to every template. I found in the docs by POLL example:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

Screenshots of the error

TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag: 'show_menu'

[image: Template Syntax Error]

[image: Base.html Error]

Under app I did:
templatetags/menu.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('menu.html')
def show_menu(menu):
    menu = Menu.objects.all()
    return {'menu': menu}
```

base.html

```
{% load menu %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    {% show_menu menu %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
Hello World! (Content)
{% endblock %}
```

Please help, what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to have actually read that documentation page you link to. Firstly, it gives explicit instructions about where to put the template tag code: not in view.py, but in a new file inside a `templatetags` directory inside your app.

Secondly, that page also explains that you need to load each tag library you use inside each template that uses them: so assuming that you've put your tag into templatetags/menu.py, you would do `{% load menu %}`.

Comment: I edited the code, as above I created folder TEMPLATETAGS under app and put MENU.PY file with the code. Then I did in the template: {% load menu %}, now I got this error: menu' is not a valid tag library: Template library menu not found, tried django.templatetags.menu,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.menu,django_admin_bootstrapped.templatetags.menu,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.menu, http://cl.ly/image/3J0t3N061e12

Comment: I found the problem by adding the "__init__.py" under the templatetags directory. Now I am having problem that "global name 'Menu' is not defined", if I add the from django.db import models
from models import Menu, it will throw an error: "'menu' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading ng.templatetags.menu: No module named models"

Comment: Why would you import the models from `django.db`? They're in your app, wherever that is. `from myapp.models import Menu`.